# How to make a simple updater for my electron app

Tags: github, electron, auto-update, electron-builder

My code so far.

#### Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "myAppName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myAppName description",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "build": "build --win"
  },
  "build": {
    "squirrelWindows": {
      "remoteReleases": "https://github.com/George/plx"
    },
    "win": {
      "certificateFile": "cert/myCerification.pfx",
      "certificatePassword": "123"
    },
    "appId": "myApp.id",
    "productName": "myAppName",
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "owner": "George",
        "repo": "plx"
      }
    ]
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/George/plx.git"
  },
  "author": "George",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/George/plx/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/George/plx#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.2",
    "electron-builder": "^15.3.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-log": "^1.3.0",
    "electron-updater": "^1.4.2" //delete
  }
}
```

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;




let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
    width: 800, 
    height: 600, 
    visible: true,
    icon: __dirname + 'build/icon.ico'
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
})

const squirrelCommand = process.argv[1];
switch (squirrelCommand) {
  case '--squirrel-install':
  case '--squirrel-updated':
  case '--squirrel-obsolete':
    app.quit();
  return true;
}
```

```css
Body{
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h5 {
  color: white;
}

h1{

  margin-top: 20%;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>1.0.0</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
  
  <h1>Version 1.0.0</h1>
  
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the command `npm run build` inside the dist/win directory I get this files:

- inside dist, I have file latest.yml and a setup.exe
- and inside the dist/win, I have my app unpacked.

How I can update my app from the GitHub repository?

I have tried to make a release on my GitHub repository, with a new version 1.0.1 but is not updating my application.

Comment: electron-updater is anything but trivial to get it running , so my advice would be to use this instead : https://github.com/megahertz/electron-simple-updater or this , https://github.com/TamkeenLMS/electron-basic-updater , this is not the answer but it will surely resolve your issue

Comment: electron-simple-updater was merged into electron-updater ;)

Comment: i have problem on step 4 and 5 https://github.com/iffy/electron-updater-example i am not sure what to select for the github access token i select only one option  from the repo i selet  Access public repositories and i press generate

Comment: after that i don know what to do with that token i have generate i have windows the exmple is used is for mac

Comment: and when i type `./publish.sh` the git bash is showing for 3 sec and after that is close ?? . i think the problem is the enviromental variable what to do??

Comment: ok, i  generate 1 more token this time all repo  checkboxes, now i nead to go  to set the toke in my environment variable on my windows

Comment: i set that token i have from github inside my windows10 system variables but when i run ./publish.sh is say **You must set the GH_TOKEN environment variable.** i dont know why i just set that token insite my machine and is not workin after that i try **export GH_TOKEN="254324684884"** and 0 output ???

Comment: 1 more think when i run ./publish.sh i have this error           $ ./publish.sh
Error: Build for macOS is supported only on macOS, please see https://github.com

Comment: develar finaly i make that updater i am sooooo hapy :) you canot imagin ,
I have a question when the program start to updating from github i notice that the program stop - close and there is not button that say ok you have updates avalaible you want to update now or you want updates later you now how to fix that issue